# AngularJS ng-repeat not repeating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning Angular JS and I am building a small app.
The first part of the app you can type in the words and it will place each word into a different array and display them in a `<ol>` list.
That part works...
The second part to it, I want to use the  to choose how many words there are and then place "*" as temp words in array for the amount of words there are.

The code is putting the "*" into the array as the array length is increasing, but the ng-repeat for the second `<ol>` only shows the first element and then stops. when the number box changes it calls this function.

```
$scope.createTempWords = function(){
    this.knownWords = [];
    var tempString = "";
    for(var i = 0; i<this.wordCount2; i++)
    {
        tempString += "_";
        if(i < this.wordCount2-1)
            tempString += " ";
    }
    this.knownWords = tempString.split(" ");
    this.count = this.knownWords.length;
}
```

the ng-repeat is link to knownWords.

The full code can be seen here http://codepen.io/SighFye/pen/bpGzwZ

Why doesn't the second ng-repeat do its job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several errors in the codebin:

1. You load Angular twice. (doesn't cause your error, just an FYI)
2. You have duplicates alert, you need to use `track by $index` on your ng-repeat.

[Codebin](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOyLvz)

Comment: Is that on both ng-repeats? Or just the second one?

Comment: So ng-repeat can not handle values being the same unless we add track by $index